# Is there a OpenForms Property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, window

In WinForms you can get a list of all open windows using Application.OpenForms? Is there a WPF version of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`Application.Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx).

Comment: Ok, follow up question. Why is Application.Windows.Current null?

Comment: I would imagine that there is no Application object for the AppDomain you're running in. Are you sure you have started one?

Comment: I wasn't aware I needed to. I figured one would be automatically created when a WPF form or control was loaded.