# WPF version of Application.OpenForms

Tags: c#, wpf, openform

I have an application in which I will have to get at another WPF window which is open. In WinForms, I was able to use:

```
MainWindow main = (MainWindow)Application.OpenForms["MainWindow"];
```

To be able to access the the form. Now in WPF it does not exist. I have seen the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810506/is-there-a-openforms-property-in-wpf) on this site which is relevant, however it uses **Application.Window** which is not contained in the call. I just have :

- Current
- Equals
- GetContentStream
- GetCookie
- GetRemoteStream
- GetResourceStream
- LoadComponet
- RefrenceEquals
- ResourceAssembly
- SetCookie

So my question is this, is there a different version for OpenForms, or is there just a different way to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at: `Application.Current`. More specifically, `Application.Current.Windows`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you know how to implement it using a window name vs. a index?

Comment: I would use LINQ: `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Where(x => x.Name == "MainWindow").FirstOrDefault()`, which will return a window named "MainWindow" or `null` if no such window is found.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Window2 wndw = new Window2();
wndw.Owner = this;

foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (w.Name == wndw.Name)
    {
        if (w.IsActive)
        {
            w.Focus();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            w.Show();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I might be late here but just in case someone needs this. If Application.OpenForms is missing on your side, that's because you have to use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms`

For example:

```
FormCollection fc = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms;
```

The fc object contains properties as: Count and InnerList(very useful)

Hope it helps, even if it is 2021, I thought that someone would need this information (I haven't seen it anywhere when I searched for it)