# how to change the color of all the textbox avaliable in Asp.net Window Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, windows

I would like to change the all the textbox color in the c# Window Application on click on button.

Comment: What do you mean by Asp.Net Windows application? Is it an intranet application, a wpf application using the browser control, a normal web application using .Net?

Comment: yes that is one type of WPF Application

Comment: Please tell us, is this asp.net web or windows application?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Window Application

Answer (score 0):

loop all the controls using for each statement, then check the type of control if textbox then set its BackgroundColor.

Comment: But all the Textbox controls are not in one form. all the textbox are in different form

Comment: In WPF app you can use theme and at runtime you can change the themes for whole app. I think that can be a feasible solution in your case

Answer (score 0):

The following function iterates all controls in the current Windows.Forms.Form. If the current control is a text box control, it sets its backcolor to red:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
    }
}
```

Edit: the question seemed to be changed from ASP.NET -> Windows application. Now we iterate the Controls collection of the current Windows.Forms.Form.

Edit2: since the question now changes to WPF: you may use the information in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877094/wpf-version-of-application-openforms) here, to retrieve all open windows in the application.

Comment: This can be change color of only one form controls i would like to in all the form which are avaliable in application