# Application.OpenForms[] Alternate for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am trying to pass variable values from One WPF `form1` to another WPF `form2`. Both Forms are open at the same time.

But i did not find any method like `Application.OpenForms` available for WinForms applications.

Someone referred me this link:

[WPF version of Application.OpenForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877094/wpf-version-of-application-openforms)

Using this link i am able to know open windows only. Is there any way to access value of a variable name `age` from `form1` to `form2`?

Comment: `Application.Current.Windows`

Comment: There are many, many, many, many articles about how to pass data among forms. There are many possible solutions and it is a matter of **personal preference** how to do it. For example, I would not use a list of open forms or windows or anything like that to pass data among forms for typical requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose the field that you want to access through a public property:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

You can then access it from another class like this provided that the window instance has been created and displayed on the screen:

```
Window1 window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>().FirstOrDefault();
if(window != null)
{
    int age = window.Age;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem Solved Using the above method