# How to Close newWindow (if it is opened already) then Open that newWindow ? WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I want to make check on button click event (which Opens newWindnow)..
If newWindow already opened it should close it first, and then open it.. As I can have dynamic Content for that newWindow everytime..
Here is code in Winform Application, But I need it for WPF

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
using (Form fc= Application.OpenForms["newWindow"])
{
if (fc!=null){
fc.Close();
nw= new newWindow(Id, Ip, name);
}
else{
nw= new newWindow(Id, Ip, name);
}
}
nw.Show();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF version of Application.OpenForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877094/wpf-version-of-application-openforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look in `Application.Current.Windows` instead of `Application.OpenForms`. The WPF equivalent would be:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fc = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<newWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (fc != null)
    {
        fc.Close();
    }
    nw = new newWindow(Id, Ip, name);
    nw.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do I know if a WPF window is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16204794/11219312)

You can create a helper method like this:

```
public static bool IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = "") where T : Window
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
       ? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any()
       : Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(w => w.Name.Equals(name));
}
```

Usage:

```
if (Helpers.IsWindowOpen<Window>("MyWindowName"))
{
   // MyWindowName is open
}

if (Helpers.IsWindowOpen<MyCustomWindowType>())
{
    // There is a MyCustomWindowType window open
}

if (Helpers.IsWindowOpen<MyCustomWindowType>("CustomWindowName"))
{
    // There is a MyCustomWindowType window named CustomWindowName open
}
```